# what is __pycache__ meant for

Tags: python, django

Today I'm trying to port my application from `Python 2.6.x` and `Django 1.7` to `Python 3.x` and `Django 1.8.x`. The problem I encounter now concerns `__pycache__`. After I ran

```
$ python3 manage.py migrate
$ python manage.py runserver
```

I see, that there appeared some folders like `__pycache__` inside of all my Django applications. My question is what this folder means? What if I create an application programmatically, and not manually with `$ python manage.py startapp myapp`, how should I create this `__pycache__` folder? What its default contents should be?

Comment: In `What is __pycache__? ` I do not see an answer to the question, how should I create this folder when I do not use `$ python manage.py startapp ...`. What its contents should be?

Comment: It's automatically created as the result of executing .py files. Ignore it. It's the same idea as the .pyc files that appear when you run .py files through Python 2